# Covariance out Issue with Generic Collection in an Interface

Tags: c#, generics, mono, covariance, xamarin

I'm a bit confused as to why I'm having this error here. Since I've declared `T` as `out`, shouldn't it be OK to return its type?

```
public interface IWebFeed<out T> where T : BaseItem
{
    List<T> getItems();

    void loadFeed();
}
```

Instead I get:

> The covariant type parameter `T' must be invariantly valid on`
>   Shared.Service.Feed.IWebFeed.getItems()'

**EDIT:** So, as mbeckish pointed out, in his link, changing the `List<T>` to `IEnumberable<T>` should resolve this, but when I follow the declaration for `IEnumerable`, I get the following:

```
using System;
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
    {
        //
        // Methods
        //

        IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in Xamarin or their PCL? The fact that `T` isn't `out`?

Comment: Totally out of subject, `but List<T> getItems();` with a lower case `g` sounds too Java. Either change it to `GetItems()` or to `Items {get;}`

Comment: Well, as I'm a Java / Objective-C programmer, playing with Xamarin / C#, that would probably be the reason :P Is that a common notation? If so, noted!

Comment: @mbeckish: I appreciate that, but I get the exact same error, changing `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @mbeckish: Please see my edit re: `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Enumerable<T> has out keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

Comment: @Josh - looks like you are correct.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14093332/21727 and http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/683/does-monotouch-support-variant-generic-interfaces

Comment: @CuongLe I'm using Xamarin, not MS C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface variance is not yet supported in MonoTouch ( Xamarin ) and should be coming in a future version as Mono has added interface variance relatively recently.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the definitionof the GetItems method to be the following...

```
List<BaseItem> GetItems();
```

This is because you are declaring a restriction on `T` that it must fit the shape of `BaseItem` and hence in order for the variance to hold you must restrict the type of items within the list. This allows you to creaet multiple lists of `BaseItem` classes and interchange them without the need for explicit conversions.